# setForeground() not working on JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have the following methods:

```
    static void display() {
    String data = "";
    try {
        input = new Scanner(file);
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            data += input.nextLine() + "\n";
        }
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        text = new JTextArea();
        text.setForeground(Color.red);
        sp = new JScrollPane(text);
        text.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        text.setOpaque(true);
        text.setVisible(true);
        text.setEnabled(false);
        text.setSize(200, 200);
        text.setText(data);
        sp.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(sp);
        frame.validate();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Score.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args){
    display();
}
```

Now when I run the file, I see this:

[Screenshot showing how the text is a weird blue instead of red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB5Xz.png)

which is as far from the specified Color.red as possible.

What am I doing wrong? Why is the foreground color not changing to red?

Comment: My guess is that the color is been overridden by the look and feel delegate (probably nimbus from the looks of it)

Comment: I have other frames and panels working perfectly fine. Only this one is having this issue.

Comment: (1-) `Only this one is having this issue.` -  Then you have proven to yourself that the method works. What is the difference between this code and the working code? Programming is about problem solving. Tell us what the difference is. Don't make us guess what the difference is. Then we can help with a solution.

Comment: There is no difference. Both frames are initialized the same way.They are just in different classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you're basic problem is `text.setEnabled(false)`, which will change the text color. Use `setEditable` instead

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
//frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(200, 200);
JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
text.setForeground(Color.red);
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(text);
text.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
text.setEditable(false);
//text.setEnabled(false);
//text.setSize(200, 200);
text.setText("Happy bunies");
frame.add(sp);
//sp.setVisible(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Swing components are already visible, so need to keep calling `setVisible(true)` on them.

When adding components to a window, add them before you make it visible, it will save you having to revalidate the container again.

Call `setSize` on the components is irrelevant, they are under the control of the layout manager API.  If you want to affect the size of the `JTextArea`, use the `setRows` and `setColumns` methods (also via the constructor).

I'd also consider using `pack` over `setSize` on the frame - but do it AFTER you've added all your components

Comment: Worked. Thanks.

Comment: I really have no memory of adding that line. Of course it wasn't working. I know setForegeround has no effect on disabled but I just didnt see that I had disabled it.